# How can I run a long Python script in a minimized Windows 10 window?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, suspend

I have along-running Windows 10 Python 3 simulation (several hours or days).  (It's easily re-startable, and it saves results regularly.)

It prints out the time periodically -- about once every 3 or 4 minutes, if the window is open.

Apparently, if the window is minimized, Windows suspends the task, and it waits for the window to be re-opened before resuming execution.  (I can see very long breaks in the screen times, corresponding to when the window is maximized.)

Is there a way I can force the program to continue executing indefinitely while its window is minimized?

From other answers, I probably want extendedExecutionUnconstrained -- how can I set that from my script?

Comment: Which distribution and version of Python are you using? Downloaded from python.org? Installed from the Microsoft Store? Something else?

Comment: Is the script a console application (e.g. python.exe)? Or does it create its own windows (e.g. pythonw.exe with a GUI toolkit)?

Comment: This is running on a desktop, so battery use is not an issue,  Python version is 3.8 for Windows 10, from PSF.  It is a console application, w/o a GUI.

Comment: Then python.exe is not a UWP app, and UWP app models are irrelevant. I suspect that you're inadvertently clicking on the console window before minimizing it, which puts the console into select mode. It will show in the title as "Select" mode, which can be entered with a single click (dragging the mouse is not required) when quick-edit mode is enabled. Try disabling quick-edit mode for the window in the console properties (not the defaults). If that solves your problem, quick-edit mode can be disabled programmatically in your script by using ctypes to call `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode`.

Comment: Another approach, if you prefer to leave quick-edit mode enabled, is to split your design into a backend thread that continuously works and a frontend thread that implements the UI via console I/O. That way if console I/O blocks due to select mode, your script will continue to function, just queuing up output that's ready to be written to the console.

Comment: Terrific!  THANKS!